# How to setup a navigation bar with image?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

Something weird and frustrating is happening with the `UINavigationBar` on `iOS7`. I'm trying to add an image like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Small.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The result is that the lettering of my header -- the Hebrew letters -- repeat all over the navigation bar.

I tried all four options for the `UIBarMetrics` flag, but with the other three the logo just disappears. I also set the image size to **320x64**, as per the documentation. But nothing seems to do the right thing, and I'm on the verge of giving up using a logo and just have a controller.title.

Comment: Set the image size? You mean 'used an image of the correct size'?

Comment: Try this, `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"Logo_Small.png"]];` for iOS7 with `320x64` image.

Answer (score 0):

If above is not working then add imageview in your NavigationBar as below code. it work.

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar@2x.png"];    
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];    
 imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);   
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the below:

```
UIImage *gradientImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Small.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4, 300, 10, 300)];// play here
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Small.png"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = iv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
   UIImage *navBarImage64 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_Small.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage64 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is actually works. The problem is that you are probably calling it after UINavigationBar was added to screen.

To verify that your code is working you can try to put into AppDelegate's didiFinishedLaunchingWithOptions.

Answer (score 0):

To customize navigation bar with Image use this,

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```